# INSERT INTO SELECT * for SQL Server, Not possible, Am I correct?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Apparently one can do

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table1 where Id=1234
```

see: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

But in SQL Server this does not work. Am I correct in thinking that SQL Server does not support the above INSERT statement, and needs to specify the columns specifically.

Thanks.

EDIT

So incomplete SQL above, now corrected

Comment: I would not use W3Schools as a reference for SQL Server. Try [Microsoft's own documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx). It's very detailed, and has lots of examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You missed the name of the table you want to insert into

```
insert into destination_table
select * from source_table
```

Of course this works only for tables with equal columns. If you only want to insert specific columns then you need to specify them too

```
insert into destination_table (col1, col2)
select col7, col3 from source_table
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have now corrected it. I am actually trying to copy a record from the same table, without typing in all the column names. There are quite a lot. I get "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.Table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON"

Comment: I think this is to do with trying to insert the same PK Identity value into the PK Identity column of the new record.

Comment: You have a column, for instance `id` that gets a value automatically. It is a unique key and no record of your table can have the same number in it. So you can't just copy a record. You need to leave that column from your query and name all the others

Comment: So the only way to copy a record, to the same table, and let the DB handle the auto increment on the Identity PK column, is to specify explicitly all the other, non PK columns ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're simply trying to copy a row from a table that has a primary key (IDENTITY column), then you can't use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table1 where Id=1234
```

This would violate the unique primary key values as it would try to insert a duplicate IDENTITY.

Instead, select all columns except the IDENTITY, assuming with this schema:

```
Table1
------
ID
Col1
Col2
Col3
```

You would do this and the IDENTITY would auto increment for you:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM Table1 
WHERE Id=1234
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Your answer came in just after juergen's confirmation of this. But I appreciate your answer as well.