# select * Within an Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm currently inserting into a table with the following prefix but also manaully set what i want in the last 2 columns ( 1,getdate() )

```
 Insert into [Table1]          
 select col1,col2,col3, 1,getdate()
 from [table2]
```

Issue is there are loads of columns and causing a mess in the SP.

I've tried to rewrite the statement with...

```
 Insert Into [table1]
 Select * from [Table2]
```

But I also need to take into consideration I want to manually write into those 2 columns..

Is there a way of doing this ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT INTO SELECT \* for SQL Server, Not possible, Am I correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886421/insert-into-select-for-sql-server-not-possible-am-i-correct)

Comment: Show us a sample schema of the two tables. Does table1 has two extra columns than table2?

Comment: `... select table2.*, 1, getdate() ...`

Comment: Outside of ad-hoc querying and `EXISTS` checks, you shouldn't use `SELECT *`. See [Bad Habits to Kick: using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: You can't really improve on this. List the columns.

Comment: @GurV Correct Table 1 has too extra columns, one is a bit flag column called deleted and the other is a datetime column called archived

Comment: @mortb nearly , that example is with a identical schema between both tables , on the other hand my situation table 1 as two extra columns to table2

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue:

```
Insert into [Table1]          
select col1, col2, col3, '1' as [col4] , getdate() as [col5] from [table2]
```

Comment: Just a comment, no need to name the selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

Two points.  First, when using `insert` you should always be in the habit of naming the columns for the insert:

```
Insert into [Table1](col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)          
    select col1, col2, col3, 1, getdate()
    from [table2];
```

Second, you do not have to put `getdate()` in the insert.  Let the database do the work for you with a default value:

```
create table table1 . . .
    col5 date default getdate()
);
```